# How to Display success message after Request sent using facebook dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an app on facebook. I can send request OR post to feed on share but I am facing problem after sending request.

I want to display success message. Something like your requests has been sent.
Actually if I talk more specifically, I need code to display success message (`requestCallback` code required) after sending request from facebook dialog.

I am working on my facebook game application: http://apps.facebook.com/siegiusarena

Any reference link OR code for `requestCallback` handler would help.

Comment: I want facebook dialog for success message.

Comment: IF THERE IS SOMETHING TO HELP FROM FACEBOOK JAVASCRIPT SDK WILL DO.

Answer (score 1):

```
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
    title: 'Title',
    message: 'Message'
},
function (res) {
    if (res && res.request) {
        // do something if the request was created
        alert('your requests has been sent');
        // or maybe something like that
        $('#messagecontainer').text('your requests has been sent');
    }
    else if (!res) {
        // do something if the request was not created
    }
});
```

EDIT:

If you want to show dialog with success message that simply looks the same as FB dialogs there are 2 ways:

1) You can use library/plugin that is designed to do this, like Facebox - http://defunkt.io/facebox/

2) You can style, for example, jQuery UI dialog on your own to achieve that, something like that - http://www.neilyoungcv.com/blog/code-share/emulating-facebooks-dialogue-using-jquery-ui-dialogues/

Comment: Let me check. Iwant facebook dialog for success message.

Comment: i modified code like:function requestCallback(response) {
 // Handle callback here
 if (response && response.request) {
  // do something if the request was created
  //alert('your requests has been sent');
  // or maybe something like that
  $('#messagecontainer').text('your requests has been sent');
 }
 else if (!res) {
  // do something if the request was not created
 }
  }

Comment: alert('your requests has been sent'); //IS NOT REQUIRED. I NEED FACEBOOK TYPE SUCCESS MESSAGE DIALOG

Comment: @FacebookLover2013 Do you want to show dialog with success message that simply looks the same as FB dialogs? I think that you need to style jQuery UI dialog to achieve that. Something like that, I think - http://www.neilyoungcv.com/blog/code-share/emulating-facebooks-dialogue-using-jquery-ui-dialogues/

Comment: @FacebookLover2013 I updated my answer with links from comments. Is it what you wanted to do?